# Magento2 hide custom option from frontend that are used for storing id's

Tags: magento2

I have my project in Magento 2.1.3

It requires to have some courses (products), that have some trainings associated to them, each training has some details

like Learner Email
Date of birth
Training Id etc.

In my form I have used the trainingId options as hidden input. But when the values are saved , along with other options the trainingId option is also visible to the user. I want to hide trainingId option along with its value from frontend. Does anyone have any suggestions regarding it?

Thanks